# PHP: Convert date/time into integer as such (no unix time conversion)

Tags: php, mysql

I have what I think should be very simple.

```
$myVar = date("Ymdhms",time());   // Ex: 20160619162358
```

When I insert $myVar into a MySQL database it gets saved in Unix Time format or something else.

```
myVar   int(15)     UNSIGNED     // field structure
1458733290                       // value stored in database instead of 20160619162358
```

How can I save $myVar as a plain integer so the database just stores it as 20160619162358? I want to convert or save $myVar as int(15).

Does this even make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: With 32-bit PHP, 20160619162358 exceeds the maximum value for a signed integer.... that could be causing you problems.... why not simply use a DATE datatype in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Use BIGINT instead of INT Type in your column;

INT unsigned can store maximum value upto 4294967295
BIGINT unsigned can store maximum value upto 18446744073709551615

Hope this solves your problem.